# Python - if statement returning True when I don't want it to

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame

The code I've just written is used so that it adjusts the value of each item in a list each time the end users scrolls, so that essentially the value of each item matches the y coordinate of its corresponding object when blitted on to the surface.

The logic behind my code looks at whether or not the difference between the original y coordinate and the new y coordinate of a object when scrolled remains the same, if not then it should proceed to the `for` loop, else move on the code following the `if` statement.

For some reason, the `if` statement keeps returning `True` even though there is no difference between the two control variables I am using.

I am not sure if I am overlooking something subtle which means that it will keep returning `True` or my logic just hasn't worked the way I expected it to; my bet is on the latter.

```
#example y values in list
yIndex = [122, 152, 212, 242]

scroll_y = 63 #initial y scroll coordinate

originalScroll_y = 63

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        #code checking whether user has scrolled
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 4 and scroll_y != 63:
                originalScroll_y = scroll_y
                scroll_y = min(scroll_y + 15, 63)
            if event.button == 5:
                originalScroll_y = scroll_y
                scroll_y = max(scroll_y - 15, finalY + 470)

        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1 and isinstance(page, MainPage):
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            control = originalScroll_y - scroll_y
            control2 = 0

            #e.g. if control = 15 and control2 = 15, it returns True instead
            #of False
            if control != control2:
                for k, j in enumerate(yIndex):
                    j -= control
                    yIndex[k] = j
                    control2 = control

            for i in yIndex:
                if y >= (i - 10) and y <= (i + 20):
                    if i in indexedContacts:
                        buttonSound.play()
                        sleep(0.5)
                        scroll_y = 63
                        page = EditPage()
                        page.style()
                        page.contactFields()
                        break
```

Comment: Could you please reduce this to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and be clearer about the suspected source of the problem?

Comment: `control2` is always zero at that `if` statement - it is set to zero a few lines earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have  a nested if statement so `control2` is set to `0`

```
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1 and isinstance(page, MainPage):
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        control = originalScroll_y - scroll_y
        control2 = 0 # set to 0 here
        if control != control2: # is 0 here
```

Control2 will never be `15` or any  value other than `0` in that if statement.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was just misthought logic. Thank you.